# Is the prestige of a university correlated with how rigorous its undergraduate courses are?

Tags: syllabus

How much harder is it to get an undergraduate degree (say, in computer science) at a highly competitive university compared to a less rigorous institution?

Comment: It depends on the state university, but generally yes. The students at a place like Stanford or MIT are simply more able than those elsewhere, and this is reflected in the difficulty of the coursework.

Comment: Given that "state university" also covers, say, Berkeley and Ann Arbor, I'd consider removing the reference (not only as you might step on some toes), replacing it with something like "...compared to a less highly ranked/less competitive university."

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to compare the difficulty of programs.  One is the minimal standards: if you're willing to seek out the easiest possible courses (and take hard courses only if they are absolutely required), how hard is it to graduate?  Another is the typical difficulty, which can differ substantially from the theoretical minimum.  And then you could ask how many students challenge themselves with particularly demanding courses.

Comment: I'm not exactly an impartial observer, but my impression is that Stanford's CS program is actually _easier_ than Illinois' CS program.  Admission, on the other hand, is a different story.

Comment: The word "correlated" sounds exactly right to me: there must be some positive correlation between the ranking of a program and its rigor/difficulty.  To say more than that you'd have to give much more precise definitions of all the terms involved: they are all a bit fuzzy.  For one thing: the least you can do to get a degree at a university can be very different from, say, the average amount of training/learning/work that students do, which in turn can be very different from what the best students / students who plan to go on to graduate study do.

Comment: There are several enormous presumptions in the question, and I disagree with most of them. E.g., "getting into" a university is not the same as "completing the program", which, if done minimal-istically, is invariably stupid in all cases, and this is not the same as "what is possible?" at a given place, or "what are the limits of the human resources at the place?" or ... So: wrong, irrelevant, misguided question, unfortunately. But de-fragging a bad question is good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct; I nevertheless do not think is it easy to quantify how much harder (or easier) is one degree compared to another. It is imperative to also define how we measure "hardness"; eg. hours per week? success rate? span of material covered? etc.
Clearly one adapts the difficulty of the lecture to the audience. I am not talking about trivializing a topic (that can happen too and it is wrong) but actually as an educator you have to strike the right balance.

To give a small anecdote from Greece:
My very close friend graduated Physics and decided to go a second degree afterwards in EECS in [NTUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Technical_University_of_Athens). EECS in NTUA in Greece is one of the most prestigious and hardest to get in schools in the country (occasionally it is actually *the hardest*). In this programme he had to do a particular Physics class and while he was good, he had to put a lot of effort on it. So at some point he asked the lecturer (I am paraphrasing) : "*I am a physicist, I know this stuff and I know you give them really hard problems on this subject. I see the class fighting to keep up; is it worth it? It is extremely unlikely they will use this material.*" the answer was : "*Yes, you are right; but they are the best (theoretically) in country so I need to drill them the hardest.*" The lecturer was adapting the lecture to the audience. And I have heard complains from academics in minor schools for the exact opposite thing (under-qualified audiences).

To recap: Yes, the same class taught in a *top* school and in a *average* school will almost surely be harder in a *top* school. That is natural and should be expected to a certain degree. Quantifying the difficulty of it though is useless unless you have a particular "yardstick*.

Disclaimer: I am not a physicist nor did I attend the institution mentioned above aside a few lectures here and there.

Comment: In general I think the answer is spot on, but I'm not sure I quite understand your anecdote.  How does someone with an undergraduate degree in physics know what will and won't be used by EECS students?  Isn't it plausible that knowing more physics than other electrical engineers will, along with other skills, make one a **really good** electrical engineer?

Comment: Probably yes, it will make a better engineer. The question was done by an EECS *student* who knew Physics; not by a *graduate*. I used it  to show that in *top* school one might cover an unusually high level of material even in subject that one would not expect it because the lecturer is adapting the lecture to the audience.